# IntelliJ Idea: Maven compilation warning about supported annotation processor source version 'RELEASE_6' on Java 11

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, java-11, mapstruct

Upon `mvn clean install` smart execution in IntelliJ Idea using Java 11 I get the following warning:

> Warning:java: Supported source version 'RELEASE_6' from annotation processor 'net.java.dev.hickory.prism.internal.PrismGenerator' less than -source '11'

How to fix it and where does it come from? Note I use:

- Lombok version `1.18.12`
- Mapstruct version `1.3.1.Final`

I have also enabled annotation processing in the IDE with default settings:

- `Build, Execution, Deployment` -> `Compiler` -> `Annotation processors` -> check `Enable annotation processing`

Comment: It is bug in idea. According to this link https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1644

Comment: I've got the same issue, have you fix it? Can you share your solution ? thx !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason can be found in the comments section, this is an IntelliJ Idea bug [IDEA-200481](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-200481).

The MapStruct issue ([1644](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1644)) at GitHub contains a comprehensive explanation [1644#437463737](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1644#issuecomment-437463737).

> See [IDEA-200481](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-200481). IntelliJ is picking up the provided dependencies when doing the compilation.
>
> **...skipped...** We can't move the `hickory` dependency to the `annotationProcessorPaths` section of the maven compiler because the `@GeneratePrisms` annotations are part of the dependency, so we won't be able to use them. If you think that we could do something on our side reopen this issue.

Comment: To add some more info. We have fixed this in 1.4 (still in Beta). We are no longer using Hickory, we use our own adaptation adaptation of it (mapstruct gem tools)

Answer (score 9):

After read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62939055/379173) answer, I solved the issue by enabling *Delegate IDE build/run actions to Maven* in the intellij settings.

Check [IDEA-200481](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-200481#focus=Comments-27-3634656.0-0) for more details.

[image: intellij settings]